# Simple social network design flaw with graph database

Tags: neo4j, social-networking, graph-databases

I was looking at graph databases and Neo4j. As suggested, I tried to draw a simple social networking graph on white paper and after a few sketches I stucked at some similar points.

At first I designed a social network where "user"s can "like" "post"s.

```
(u1:User)-[:LIKED]->(p:Post)<-[:POSTED]-(u2:User)
```

Now I want to notify user2 about the like action and draw this on the white paper.

```
(u1:User)-[:LIKED]->(p:Post)<-[:POSTED]-(u2:User)
              |                            ^
              |__________[:NOTIFY]_________|
```

I am not sure if it is clear but I just drew a relationship between a node and another relationship which is not possible for graph databases, at least for Neo4j. So I decided, a `Like` should be a node instead of a relationship. Then my graph turned into this.

```
(u1:User)-[:CREATAD]->(l:Like)-[:BELONGS_TO]->(p:Post)<-[:POSTED]-(u2:User)
                          |                                           ^
                          |__________________[:NOTIFY]________________|
```

Now everything is OK. Then I added Comments feature to the system as a relationship but when notifications involved, again it turned into a node. And same happened when I added "Liking comments" feature, "Likes to Comments" first seemed they are relationships but once again they turned into nodes when notifications involved.

In general, at some point I find myself drawing a relationship between a node and another relationship. My solution to that feels like I am turning entities, which naturally look like relationships, into nodes. And this makes me think of I have some problems with deciding what should be a node and what should be a relationship.

So my question is, does anyone else other than me fall into this **"relationship between a node and another relationship"** issue and if so how do you solve that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It all depends on your use-cases, in many cases a simple relationship is good enough but if you want to do more with that entity or fact you turn it into a node, oftentimes it turns out that it is an actually quite important concept in the domain.

In our data modeling class there is a specific section on this and also in the "Graph Databases" book it is discussed in detail (you can get the [free PDF here](http://graphdatabases.com)).

Sometimes it makes sense to keep the original relationship around for a fast shortcut crossing over that intermediate node if you don't need that detail.